# Why nasm and yasm yield 67 opcode for mov r16, word [r64 - 3] instruction?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, instruction-set, yasm

In **x86-64** assembly I have following instruction

```
mov        dx, word [esi-5]
```

Nasm `2.13.03` generates:

```
66 67 8B 56 FB
```

yasm `1.3.0` generates:

```
67 66 8B 56 FB
```

The `66 67` opcodes are modifiers so `8B 56 FB` on its own is:

```
 mov        edx, dword [rsi-5]
```

I noticed that:

```
66 8B 56 FB
```

also evaluates to:

```
mov        dx, word [rsi-5]
```

I have two questions:
1) Why `nasm` & `yasm` emit this `67` opcode byte padding? (`67` on it's own is not enough to reduce `edx` to `dx`, it needs to include `66` )
2) Is there a way to emit a shorter 4 byte instruction **without** `67` in nasm / yasm?

Comment: None of this makes sense.  First of all, the instruction ends with `fb`, the `85` is part of the next instruction.  Second, even then, `66 67 8b 46 fb` disassembles to `mov ax, word [esi-5]` which is not quite the same as you posted.  Did you make a mistake transcribing this somewhere?

Comment: 67 should make the address into [esi-3] and without it it will be [rsi-3] so somewhere there’s a problem

Comment: @fuz last byte was redudant ,I removed it . Anyway `66 8B 56 FB` in Hopper evaluates to `mov        dx, word [rsi-3]`

Comment: @Kamil.S No, that's not correct.  `66 8b 56 fb` is `mov dx, word [rsi-5]`.  Did you make an error transcribing this somewhere?

Comment: @fuz I hate to admit but I did , the difference is in `word [rsi-5]` vs `word [esi-5]`

Comment: @Kamil.S Exactly, as Sami Kuhmonen already said.  Unless you must ignore the high bits of `rsi` or rely on `esi` being sign extended, you can usually change `[esi-5]` to `[rsi-5]` without ill effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question made **false** assumption `66 8B 56 FB`

```
mov        dx, word [rsi-5]
```

is equivalent to

```
`66 67 8B 56 FB` or `67 66 8B 56 FB` 

mov        dx, word [esi-5]
```

`66` reduces `edx` to `dx`
`67` reduces `[rsi-5]` to `[esi-5]`

Comment: BTW, you might want `movzx edx, word [rsi-5]`, [to avoid potential partial-register slowdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) either from later reading edx, or on some CPUs to avoid a false dependency.  Also, `0xFB = 256-5`.  Your machine code definitely has a `-5` displacement, not `-3`.

Comment: @PeterCordes `movzx` is very neat suggestion , much appreciated